# Finding correlation of discrete distribution data

Tags: distributions, correlation, discrete-data, covariance-matrix, covariance

I'm not good at Statistics but I need to use it to summarize my case study.
So I consult with a person who're good at Statistics. He suggested that
My data is discrete because all the values are integer and some are duplicated as shown below. I want to find correlation between x and y of the two data sets below. In data set 1, x and y are discrete. In data set 2, x is discrete but y is continuous.

**Data Set 1**

```
 x   y
-5  -19
-5  -21
-5  -23
-5  -23
-4  -17
-4  -17
-4  -18
-4  -19
-4  -19
-4  -23
-4  -19
-4  -18
-3  -13
-3  -20
-3  -17
-3  -15
-3  -17
-3  -18
-3  -18
-3  -18
-3  -18
-3  -18
-3  -18
-3  -15
-3  -15
-2  -15
-2  -15
-2  -14
-2  -14
-2  -11
-2  -12
-1  1
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
```

**Data Set 2**

```
1   287.92
1   340
1   219.62
1   30
1   30
1   292.56
-2  -70.32
-2  -82.04
-2  -68.53
-2  -68.53
-2  -51.89
-2  -57.36
-3  -94.01
-3  -66.61
-3  -95.91
-3  -95.91
-3  -95.91
-3  -95.91
-3  -95.91
-3  -95.91
-3  -78.14
-3  -125.34
-3  -78.14
-4  -110.45
-4  -94.01
-4  -94.01
-4  -162.85
-4  -162.85
-4  -162.85
-4  -120.93
-5  -307.67
-5  -123.19
-5  -371.38
-5  -166.91
-5  -162.85
-5  -302.21
-5  -176.42
-5  -307.67
-5  -371.38
-6  -390.71
-6  -387.74
```

so he suggested me to find covariance and then find the correlation from covariance

**question 1**: Should I use *sample* covariance or *population* covariance

Its difference is that in sample covariance, the average of X and Y in the sample are used; whereas in population covariance, ux and uy are used.

**question 2**: some books mentioned the equation of population covariance that

pop_cov = sigma(xi-ux)(yi-uy)  /   N

others said

pop_cov = sigma(xi-ux)(yi-uy) = sigma(XY)- (uxuy)

Which one is correct?

**question 3**: if the answer of question 1 is population covariance, how can I get the probability of occuring each value of X (p(x)), each value of Y(p(y)), and occuring a particular X and Y (p(x,y)). Can I calculate these 3 probabilities from the sample I have, for example p(5) is 4/39 (4 is a number of 5 and 39 is total number of X).

**question 4**: the formula of correlation need standard deviation (corr = covariance/(sdx sdy)), will we use standard deviation of population or sample ( is it depending on the type of covariance we use, of pop or sample)?

Thank you very much. I 'm sorry that I am so novice about Statictiscs

Comment: A *population* is what you're trying to learn about; the *sample* consists of the data have.  Therefore, *you don't know any of the population parameters* (such as its mean or standard deviation).  Consequently it's impossible to *calculate* the population parameters: you have to *estimate* them from the sample.  I believe that eliminates all these questions, although possibly not question 3, because I cannot make sense of the notation.

Comment: Computing correlation involving a categorical variable is not advisable because a simple relabeling of the categories will give you a different estimate and possibly different hypothesis test decisions. This is clearly true with nominal data, but can be true with ordinal data as well if the variable is re-leveled in a non-linear way.

Answer (score 1):

If your discrete data are in fact ordinal (there's a monotone relation between categories, so larger values represent "better", in some sense, answers), you would want to compute polyserial corrrelations (on which your statistics person would probably need to read; my quick googling, for an unpleasant surprise, did not produce much meaningful stuff -- see [this](http://ideas.repec.org/a/spr/psycho/v61y1996i3p427-443.html) though).

If your discrete data are nominal (e.g., color of a car, industry of a firm, etc.), then the most sensible measures of association would be provided by ANOVA.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the correlation coefficient BUT a problem arises when you try and determine the statistical significance of the computed cc . A favorite reference of mine http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/dbs202/cat/stats/corr.html illustrates that the data being analyzed need to bivariate normal. One of your series is clearly not. Note also that the data must not be autocorrelated because that would violate bivariate normality. This last point is not relevant to you but should be of interest to other readers who endeavor to interpret simple cross-correlations when dealing with time series or spatial data.  Hope this helps ! This upon reflection seems more like a comment but in summary neither of your proposals seem adequate. I would think that a non-parametric test might be in order.